Implications on Farey distance from Diophantine approximation
I tried searching for this online but haven't really found anyone answering this sort of questions.
I am interested in what Diophantine approximation properties imply on the Farey distance.
If I am not mistaken, the $n$-th Farey numbers are given by $F_n:=\{ \frac{j}{n}: 0\leq j \leq n \} \cup F_1 \cup ... \cup F_{n-1}$, where $F_1=\{0,1\}$. For distinct $x,y\in (0,1)$, the Farey distance is defined to be $d_F(x,y)=\frac{1}{n+1}$, where $n$ is the largest  index such that $x$ and $y$ are strictly between two consecutive $n$-Farey numbers. I know that Farey distance is bounded from below by half the standard Euclidean distance. But I was wondering whether a qualitative inverse sort of inequality is possible. More accurately, if for a Liouville number $x\in (0,1)$ there exists $C(x;\alpha)>0$ and infinitely many rationals $\frac{p_n}{q_n}$, such that $d_F(x,\frac{p_n}{q_n})\leq  \frac{C(x;\alpha)}{q_n^\alpha}$ for $\alpha>2$?
I suspect that the answer to this question is known, but I was not able to find something of the sort.
